# Python how to use Threading in multi download

Tags: python, python-requests

I am use `threading` to do parallel download now i have a url_list `img_list` i want to download it in 2 thread so def two download.

i put half into `download1` and half in `download2` so it will speed up to complete, but finally when i run the scripts my download still in serial,i don't know why, how can i modify my script?

here's the code:

```
import requests,threading
img_list=[...]
num=len(img_list)
def download_1(img_list):
    n=0
    for i in img_list:
        n+=1
        with open('./img/'+str(n)+'.jpg','wb')as f:
            f.write(requests.get(i).content)
            print(str(n)+"download1 complete")
def download_2(img_list):
    n=len(img_list)
    for i in img_list:
        n+=1
        with open('./img/'+str(n)+'.jpg','wb')as f:
            f.write(requests.get(i).content)
            print(str(n)+"download2 complete")
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=download_1(img_list[:int(num/2)]))
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=download_2(img_list[int(num/2):]))
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```py
threading.Thread(target=download_1(img_list[:int(num/2)]))
```

you call `download_1(...)` and pass the result (null) to thread. That's why it runs serially. Instead you want to pass `download_1` function itself (not the result of calling it) to the thread. Like this:

```py
threading.Thread(target=download_1, args=(img_list[:int(num/2)],))
```

Do it in both places.

*Side note:* you should `t.join()` both threads at the end.

Comment: why to use ```,```in ```args=(img_list[:int(num/2)],)```, when i use ```args=(img_list[:int(num/2)])``` it cause error

Comment: @M_Sea because in Python `args=(1)` is the same as `args=1` while `args=(1,)` actually means a tuple of size 1 containing 1.That's one of those nasty things about Python that you just have to learn. And `args` tuple corresponds to consecutive arguments (your function accepts only 1 argument).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both functions at the time of creating threads. So, threads are passed null and, therefore, do nothing. You should change the code like this:

```
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=download_1, args=(img_list[:int(num/2)]))
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=download_2, args=(img_list[int(num/2):]))

thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
```